# Automatically collect filenames matching several different patterns in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

By default, pytest collects all files named according to `test_*.py`. But I also want it to run on all files named `example_*.py`. I can't figure out how to do this.

According to [their docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html), you can change the naming convention in the configuration files from `test_*` to something else. But if I try to to a glob pattern matching both `test_*` and `example_*` (mainly, `{example,test}_*.py`), it doesn't work. At least on Windows.

Anyone have an idea of how to match both `test_*.py` and `example_*.py` with pytest?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out by searching for `python_files` in the repo, then found a buried example. This works:

```
python_files = test_*.py *_test.py testing/*/*.py example_*.py
```

You just add spaces between all the patten matches you want. Not sure this is documented. I've put an issue [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3824) to see if it's worth expanding on.